# How to publish elements to a kafka topic while processing the elements in the PCollection<KV<String,String>> in ParDo function in apache beam?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-beam

I have a `PCollection<KV<String,String>> Pcol`, I am processing each element in the `ParDo` method. I want to publish records based on some condition to kafka topic in the pardo itself.

How do I do this?

```
PCollection<KV<String, String>> Pcol =pipeline.apply("Process Data", 
    ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, String>, KV<String, String>>() {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws IOException {
            String key = element.getKey();
            if(key==null)
            {//publish to a kafka topic}
        }
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Beam, Sinks are usually implemented by ParDo. So you could refer to how Kafka sinks are implemented in Beam for ideas how to write to Kafka within ParDo. More specifically, these two classes might helpful:[1](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaWriter.java) and [2](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaExactlyOnceSink.java).